Django Environment Identifying the DEBUG as False while it is set to True
I get and error
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False
Below are the edits I attempted seeing at stackoverflow's suggestion from various queries around 5 of them were relevant and tried to edit accordingly.
... I also checked for views and urls for any filename mistyping and typo errors. Yet I am getting
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
I closed the session and changed the open .py file default from vscode and then with python. Yet this error is persistent  PLEASE HELP
My settings.py has DEBUG = TRUE
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
I have also tried ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
then ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
then ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1'] 
then ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1'] 
once with DEBUG = FALSE and then with DEBUG = TRUE
Alternately I Tried this
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

if not DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOST = ['0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1','localhost','*']

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []```

The issue still persists despite Changing VS code settings .py extension change from VSCODE to Python interpreter and vice versa.


Are you sure your settings file doesn't repeat the DEBUG setting but as False? If it doesn't are you sure you're looking at the correct settings file? You're running your code using manage.py right? What does it configure DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to? Perhaps do you have that environment variable set in your environment?

do you really have DEBUG = TRUE ?  the capitalisation matters, in Python the true and false are spelled like True or False

I have used this to check
DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG') == "True")
Alternately also tried:
DEBUG = (os.getenv('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'True') == "True")
The problem still persists.
Yes the True is written according to python syntax.

First and foremost, your variable is wrong.
if not DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOST = ['0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1','localhost','*']

this should be ALLOWED_HOSTS (with an S)
the allowed_hosts should be something like this:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1',]

regardless if you're in debug or not, this MUST be set.
I'd further recommend something like this to ensure you get a value for allowed_hosts:
if not DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<prod DNS, host, and/or IP>',]
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1',]


I would further make sure that DEBUG isn't getting set/reset somewhere else in your settings.py file.

I made the typo corrections and alternately used following methods to check whether DEBUG is being interrupted
DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG') == "True")
then with this:
DEBUG = (os.getenv('DJANGO_DEBUG', 'True') == "True")
The error still persists
https://github.com/kromation/Python/tree/main/Blog%20API
This is the project repo
I am using venv.
I also tried print(DEBUG)
and run the server using
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Alternately
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

I think you're making this more difficult than it has to be
from one of my apps
import socket
try:     HOSTNAME=socket.gethostname() except:     HOSTNAME='localhost'
I also know my QA and PRD hostnames and set those up as constants:
HOSTNAME_PRD='hostname.domain.com' HOSTNAME_QA='hostnameqa.domain.com' 
then in my code, I check to see if i need to make DEBUG=True (default to DEBUG  False)
DEBUG = False if HOSTNAME != HOSTNAME_QA and HOSTNAME != HOSTNAME_PRD: # Check for non-local hostname     DEBUG = True    # if not QA and not PRD (must be local) set DEBUG = True

also, i wouldn't be publishing the secret key in your git. I know that is a key you want to keep private ;o)

created a fork for your settings.py file in your git repo.  Please review and let me know if that helps or not.

Are you suggesting to implement this in settings.py?
or Are you saying it to Implement it in another file. Could you please mention the file where this is to be tried.
In settings.py when used throws same error again.

I went to your git repo this AM and made some suggested changes. I think there's a PR waiting for you. this will clean up your settings.py file and fix the issue.. or should :)

It did work. I remember putting smallcase in all filenames. I wonder how this one got missed. Thank you!

AWESOME. if this answers your question, please consider accepting it as the 'accepted' answer. cheers!
